# How can I check if Civicrm mails sent through scheduled Cron are bounced or sent successfully?

Tags: scheduled-reminders, bounce

I can see scheduled reminder in the activity logs and also see the Cron Logs
but  I am unsure how I can see bounced emails which was bounced while sending mail under scheduled reminder.

I even checked it under advanced search and selected "Contact on Hold" but it gave empty result.
Does that mean no emails were bounced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think CiviCRM currently offers a way to catch bounced messages from sending an email direct from a contact record, or via Scheduled Reminders.

The only 'bounce' processing that occurs, afaik, is when CiviMail is used.

Comment: Noting that discussions here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15410/measure-open-rates-for-standard-emails-from-civi-not-from-civimail/15449#15449 may also provide a solution for bounce tracking

Answer (score 2):

As Pete indicates, reports for individual emails are not available through the GUI, but depending on how your mail is handled (e.g. through a service such as SendGrid or through a mail server) then you should be able to view bounces for any communication sent directly from the service provider's portal or by reports that can be generated directly from the server.

Hope this helps,
Tamar